# Why we have to import formsmodule in angular 6

Tags: angularjs, angular6

I am good in angular 1 now I am moving to angular 6. To use ngModel on input why we need Formsmodule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See officiel documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview)

Both reactive and template-driven forms share underlying building blocks.

- A FormControl instance that tracks the value and validation status of an individual form control.
- A FormGroup instance that tracks the same values and status for a collection of form controls.
- A FormArray instance that tracks the same values and status for an array of form controls.
- A ControlValueAccessor that creates a bridge between Angular FormControl instances and native DOM elements.